# Incompatibility between sigplanconf's \thanks and cleveref

Tags: titles, cleveref, sigplanconf

There seem to be an incompatibility between `cleveref` and the `\thanks` command of the `sigplanconf` class (see [here](http://www.sigplan.org/Resources/Author/) for more info).

Here's a MWE showing the issue (using the latest `sigplanconf` v3.2):

```
\documentclass{sigplanconf}

\usepackage{cleveref}% Commenting this makes the example compile just fine

\begin{document}


\title{Title}

% \authorinfo{Au Thor}% without \thanks cleveref is not an issue
\authorinfo{Au Thor\thanks{a}}
{University of Nowhere}
{author@nowhere.edu}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this and use both `cleveref` and `\thanks` with `sigplanconf`?

Comment: `\@maketitle` contains `\let\thanks=\titlenote`. Commenting this out, it will work, but this is not a solution of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class doesn't define `\@thefnmark` when `\thanks` is processed, because it doesn't call `\footnote`, but `\titlenote`. However `cleveref` expects a definition for `\@thefnmark` like in standard footnotes. Just provide a definition for it in a way compatible with how `sigplanconf` works. Such a definition will be overridden when real footnotes are processed, but as `\thanks` can only appears before `\maketitle`, no problem should arise.

```
\documentclass{sigplanconf}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\@thefnmark}{\the\@fnmark}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\authorinfo{Au Thor\thanks{a}}
  {University of Nowhere}
  {author@nowhere.edu}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this weird since the class is based on `article`? It does execute `\LoadClass{article}` inside, shouldn't this properly setup `\@thefnmark`?

Comment: could you please explain your comment on standard classes? The class is based on `article` but I cannot find the definition of `\@thefnmark` in `article.cls`; yet `cleveref` works perfectly with `article` and `\thanks`...

Comment: @Bordaigorl I've made some more investigation.